# No Data in GCM Recieved notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

I am using below code to send notification to client using GCM. The below code is written on button onClickListener in MainActivity.class. The notification is successfully sent and received. When i try to read the notification information it does not have any

//Send Notification code//

```
String to = "To_sendor_id";
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
            data.putString("my_action", "SAY_HELLO");
            String id = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt("1"));
            try {
                gcm.send(to + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String msg = "Sent message";
            Log.d("Sent",msg);
```

//Receiver Code

```
 public class SeriousBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try { String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i("messages","action=" + action);
        if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
            String payload = intent.getStringExtra("my_message");
            Log.i("messages", "payload=" + payload);
            String action = intent.getStringExtra("my_action");
            Log.i("messages", "action=" + action);
            Log.i("messages " , intent.getExtras().toString());}  finally {

    }
}
```

output of last Log.i :  I/messages: Bundle[{message_type=send_event, event=sent, google.message_id=1}]

Comment: why are you not using .. `GcmListenerService` ? or try to get the Bundle from intent and than String from bundle.

Comment: I will explore on how to use GCMListener. But could you let me know whats wrong with the code i am using

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `GcmListenerService` instead `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` like this :

```
public class EMSListenerService extends GcmListenerService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        super.onMessageReceived(from, data);

        String my_message = data.getString("my_message");
        String my_action = data.getString("my_action");

        //do something here

    }
}
```

Don't forget to add service to menifest file like this :

```
<service
android:name=".services.EMSListenerService"
android:exported="false" >
 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
 </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But could you please explain what is wrong with the code i am using.

Comment: Hi Dhaval, I have implemented the code as you suggested but EMSListenerService is not getting called.But works well when i send a notification using Curl

Comment: It's quite strange. Because as you implemented it should be called.

Comment: Have you added following receiver in menifest?

<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: yes . i did impemneted reciever then only curl nitrification triggers the reciver :)

Comment: Actually I am also finding that what is wrong with this. As much as I know the receiving part is well implemented according google documentation. But I never tried sending like you did. So let's find out what is wrong.

Comment: I am referring this. You should also review this.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream#sample-send

Comment: Can you provide me the code to send notification from device to device. I already spent a lot of time and no success.

Comment: As I told I haven't implemented for device to device. I did for php to Android. That's why I gave the reference link where they provide documentation for upstreaming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112460/discussion-between-go-sgenq-and-dhaval).